# Copy files using WinSCP: Permission denied

Tags: file-permissions, winscp, google-compute-engine

**Platform**: Google Compute Engine

**VM instance**: pytorch-latest-gpu-20190911

**login command**: `$ gcloud compute ssh jupyter@my-fastai-instance -- -L 8080:localhost:8080`

In order to save GCP billing time, I cloned the fastai course v3 and libraries on my local machine which allows me to play with non-compute intensive operations like data set creation, etc.

So after creating several datasets locally, I tried to copy the folders to my vm instance using WinSCP. But I got ‘Permission denied’ error. After much frustration, I found this was due to the /home directories being owned by ‘jupyter’. I then used $ `sudo chown -R my-username ~/jupyter` to change ownership to my username. This allowed me to copy all my local data to gce via WinSCP. But when I attempted to run my notebooks in gce, they would not run. In order to run them, I had to revert ownership back to ‘jupyter’.

So my question is this: how can I change /home owner to my_username but still allow Jupyter to run my notebooks? Is this a setting within Jupyter or do I need to do something else? My goal is to freely transfer files with WinSCP without messing with changing jupyter ownership of the directories.

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP.net has published a detailed description of the procedure to follow in the article
[Connecting Securely to Google Compute Engine Server with SFTP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_google_compute_engine).

The article itself is much too long and detailed to reproduce here.
In a nutshell, it describes how to:

- Generate your private key
- Collect information about your GCE instance
- Set up SSH keys for your Google Compute account
- Setup the WinSCP login

Answer (score 1):

never worked in that same scenario, but I would guess that jupyter is just a typical user with a home folder. You could have added your username to the jupyter group instead of taking ownership.

When you run `ls -l /home` you can see the current permissions of the user folders. Take for instance:

```
ls -l /home | grep jupyter
drwxr-xr-x 13 jupyter jupyter   4096 Sep  8 10:26 jupyter
```

The first `jupyter` is the username, the second `jupyter` is the group name. You can see the permissions are:

- `rwx` for user `jupyter`.
- `r-x` for members of group `jupyter`.
- `r-x` for the rest of the users.

In that case you could add your user to the group `jupyter` editing `/etc/group/`:

```
jupyter:x:1001:bill
```

and then add the appropriate permissions for the group:

```
chmod -R g+w /home/jupyter
```

Which basically means 'recursively change permissions in /home/jupyter to add write permissions to the group'. Now you should see the permissions like:

```
ls -l /home | grep jupyter
drwxrwxr-x 13 jupyter jupyter   4096 Sep  8 10:26 jupyter
```

Note the difference, now the UGO permissions (User, group, other) are 'drwxr**w**xr-x'